# jQuery get different values from same element and use them as different classes

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm struggling trying to find a way to get the text of child elements and use them as separate classes for the parent element. I kinda got the logic but can't find a way to separate each class.

To add more complication, I want to remove special characters, replace blank spaces and put everything lowercase. I think I already got this part (hopefully).

Anyway... I have this html code:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Child #1</div>
   <div class="child">Child #2</div>
   <div class="child">Child #3</div>
   <div class="child">Child #4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Child #A</div>
   <div class="child">Child #b</div>
   <div class="child">Child #9</div>
   <div class="child">Child #K</div>
</div>
```

What I want to see is the following:

```
<div class="parent new_child_1 new_child_2 new_child_3 new_child_4">
   <div>Child #1</div>
   <div>Child #2</div>
   <div>Child #3</div>
   <div>Child #4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent new_child_a new_child_b new_child_3 new_child_1">
   <div>Child #A</div>
   <div>Child #b</div>
   <div>Child #3</div>
   <div>Child #1</div>
</div>
```

So I got this so far:

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
        var child_text = $(this).find(".child").text();
        var new_class = child_text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '_').toLowerCase()
        $(this).addClass("new_" + new_class);
});
```

But I get a single string of all the texts (i.e. "new_child_1child_2child_3child_4").

Thanks to everyone who will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array from the children and use `Array.reduce`, like this:

```js
$(".parent").each(function() {
  var children = $(this).find('.child');
  var new_class = Array.from(children).reduce((carry, child) => {
    var text = child.innerText.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

    carry += `new_${text} `;

    return carry;
  }, '');
  console.log(new_class);
  $(this).addClass(new_class);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child #1</div>
  <div class="child">Child #2</div>
  <div class="child">Child #3</div>
  <div class="child">Child #4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child #A</div>
  <div class="child">Child #b</div>
  <div class="child">Child #9</div>
  <div class="child">Child #K</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it!
Thank to everyone who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

you're iterating on the parent only, you need to iterate on the children directly.
I haven't tried this yet, but I believe it should be close.

```
$(".parent").children().each(function(){
        var child_text = $(this).text();
        var new_class = child_text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '_').toLowerCase()
        $(this).addClass("new_" + new_class);
});
```

Edit: If you just need to add a space, you can do that within the function:

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
        var child_text = $(this).find(".child").text();
        var new_class = child_text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '_').toLowerCase()
        // check if newclass has data, if it does, add a leading space
        if (new_class.length > 0) { $(this).addClass(" new_" + new_class); );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work as it adds a single class with all the texts of the elements instead of adding a single class for each child element's text

Comment: You want the parent to have the classes of all the "new_child" applies to it instead of the children?

Comment: yes, I would like to see the parent element have different classes named as the text of each child element it contains. All of them with a "new_" prefix. The only thing I can't get to work is to divide all the texts in different classes. I only manage to create a huge class whose name is the junction of all the texts of the children elements.

Comment: I added an edit that may work, to separate the names properly.

Comment: Thank you again or the reply and for the help. Unfortunately it still creates only one class "new_child_1child_2child_3child_4" instead of 4 different classes "new_child_1 new_child_2 new_child_3 new_child_4".

Comment: glad you found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the character you want is always after a #, you can use a split function, like this

EDITED

```js
$(".parent").each(function() {
  var childs = [];
  $(this).find(".child").each(function(key) {
    childs[key]='new_child_'+$(this).text().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '_').toLowerCase();
    $(this).removeClass('child');
  });

  console.log(childs.join(' '));
  $(this).addClass(childs.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child #1</div>
  <div class="child">Child #2</div>
  <div class="child">aBc*d#</div>
  <div class="child">Child #4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child #A</div>
  <div class="child">Child #b</div>
  <div class="child">Child #9</div>
  <div class="child">Child #K</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, the text will be random and will not always contain a #.

Comment: Code edited, somthing like that?

Comment: Yes, this works as well! Thank you!